# Jenkins reports a cycle dependcy error with plugins after restart and will not start now

Tags: jenkins, jcasc

We restarted our jenkins LTS 2.303.3 (which redownloads all plugins upon restart with the JCaSC plugin) and are seeing these errors in the logs:

```
2022-07-27 17:59:00.565+0000 [id=31] SEVERE hudson.PluginManager$1$3$2$1#reactOnCycle: found cycle in plugin dependencies: (root=Plugin:sshd, deactivating all involved) Plugin:sshd -> Plugin:mina-sshd-api-core -> Plugin:ssh-credentials -> Plugin:credentials -> Plugin:configuration-as-code -> Plugin:sshd
2022-07-27 17:59:00.569+0000 [id=31] SEVERE hudson.PluginManager$1$3$2$1#reactOnCycle: found cycle in plugin dependencies: (root=Plugin:sshd, deactivating all involved) Plugin:sshd -> Plugin:mina-sshd-api-core -> Plugin:ssh-credentials -> Plugin:credentials -> Plugin:configuration-as-code -> Plugin:sshd
2022-07-27 17:59:00.570+0000 [id=31] SEVERE hudson.PluginManager$1$3$2$1#reactOnCycle: found cycle in plugin dependencies: (root=Plugin:sshd, deactivating all involved) Plugin:sshd -> Plugin:mina-sshd-api-core -> Plugin:ssh-credentials -> Plugin:credentials -> Plugin:configuration-as-code -> Plugin:trilead-api -> Plugin:sshd
```

Jenkins fails to start and we did not change any versions of our plugins oddly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some digging, it looks like theres an issue with the mina-sshd-api-core plugin: https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-69034 This link states you can fix by upgrading the configuration as code plugin, but that did not fix it for our case.

We downgraded that mina-sshd-api-core plugin to the following version to get our isntance back up and running.

Working version: mina-sshd-api-core:2.8.0-18.vd98674ecd652